# Setting a static home page and blog page without using the settings

Tags: themes, frontpage, customization, blog-page

This may seem like a stupid question, and it probably isn't possible, but is it possible for me to set a static home page (using `front-page.php`) and a blog page (using `home.php`, I think) in my theme, **and** have the blog page appear on a separate slug WITHOUT changing the page settings in my Wordpress installation, under `Settings > Reading`?  So http://www.mysite.com/blog/ will show my blog (`home.php`), and http://www.mysite.com/ will show my home page (`front-page.php`)?

**EDIT**
I should point out, as I didn't point it out so explicitly earlier, I would like to avoid creating the pages in Wordpress, if I can.  Although @eyedarts does answer the question, it doesn't give completely what I need.  Although that may well have been my fault for not explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be that it is possible:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

**Configuration of front-page.php**

> If it exists, the front-page.php template file is used on the site's
>   front page regardless of whether 'Settings > Reading ->Front page
>   displays' is set to "A static page" or "Your latest posts," the Theme
>   will need to account for both options, so that the site front page
>   will display either a static page or the blog posts index. There are a
>   few methods to do so.

As for the blog page, I think you can find what you're looking for here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

**Specialized Page Template**

> Create a template for one Page: For more extensive changes, intended
>   for just one specific Page, you can create a specialized template
>   file, named with that Page's slug or ID:
>
> ```
>     page-{slug}.php
>     page-{ID}.php
> ```

In that specialized/custom template file, use the get_posts() function (http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and other similar functions to get and list the posts.

You can use the add_posts_page() function (http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_posts_page/) to add the page to the menu.

So, in your front-page.php, you'll have a reference to a static page that you create in your code. You'll then also create a second page for your blog page using the specialized page template.

I'd be curious to know if there's an easier, more straight-forward way to do this.

Comment: I know that `front-page.php` will override the home page, but `page-{slug}.php` doesn't seem to work for the blog; it throws up a 404 error page instead.  It was something I had tried before, but to no avail.  Unless there is something that I have forgotten to add somewhere.

Comment: My understanding of the `page-{slug}.php` pages is that it still requires a page to be set up in Wordpress, in order that it pulls the slug in.  I would like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Hopefully someone else will help as I'm curious about this too.

Answer (score -1):

Create the home.php and rewrite the address in your .htacess file in the main wordpress folder.

Just below this

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Add this

```
RewriteRule    ^/home/$    http://www.example/blog/    [301,L]
```

If you later change the permalinks in WP admin page this line may be overwritten and you may have to add it again.